# What should be the optimal way of solving Recurrence relation for really Huge number greater than Integer maximum value

Tags: java, arrays, recurrence

I want to find the Nth number of the Recurrence Equation

```
T(n)=T(n-1)+3T(n-2)+3T(n-3)+(n-4),T(1)=T(4)=1,T(2)=T(3)=3
```

so if suppose you entered 2,5,9 as input, output should be `T(2)=3,T(5)=20,T(9)=695`

what I did is create an array of size equal to  maximum of all input value and storing solution of T(i) at index i.Then look up into the array for specific index. eg array[3] for T(3),array[5] for T(5),etc

The code worked fine till maximum number is not greater than maximum integer value system can hold i.e

```
Integer.MAXValue.
```

Because the index of array can only be integer then
if number is  `n=1855656959555656` what should be the best way to find the solution of 
`T(1855656959555656)`?
as clearly  I cant create an array of `size=1855656959555656..`

I have even tried **BigInteger** from `java.Math`  but with no success.
I have to find some other approach.please suggest some ideas..

Thanks

Comment: Yoy want precalculate all values? maxvalue array will be 16GB size. It isn't best use of space. (because you need at least longs to store value.

Comment: Yes exactly.This isn't the best of Algo to solve this kind of relations.But I am not able to think of other than this as of now. @talex

Comment: There is an answer already. But you run into another problem. Value grows is exponential. You will have memory problem trying to store T(MAX_INT) value

Comment: Have you tried writing in file the intermediate output

Comment: @ Mujtaba Hasan  yes I have tried..every logic seems working until number gets really big...eg. n=1855656959555656..execution gets almost stuck and timeout..

Answer (score 4):

you do not need to store every T(i), you only need to store 3 values T(i-1), T(i-2), T(i-3). While looping over i, check if the current i should be part of your output, if so put it out immediately or save it to an "output"-array.

edit: this part is quite inefficient. You check in every iteation EVERY needed output.

```
        for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; ++k) {
            if (count == arr[k])
                T[k] = temp[i];
            else if (arr[k] == 1)
                T[k] = 1;
            else if (arr[k] == 2)
                T[k] = 3;
            else if (arr[k] == 3)
                T[k] = 3;
            else if (arr[k] == 4)
                T[k] = 1;
        }
```

so your code runs in time (max*arr.length) you can reduce it to only (max). Use a HashMap with key=neededPosition (=count) value=position in arr

Init the map like this:

```
 Map<Long, Integer> map = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();
 for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        map.put(arr[i], i);
    }

if (map.containsKey(count)) {
    T[map.get(count)] = temp[i]
}
```

check the values 1-4 just once after the whole thing!

Comment: sounds like a good alternative.let me write it and i 'll get back to you.

Comment: While I think this solves the actual problem, it may not help people getting here searching for large arrays (reading the title of the post....)

Comment: @Michael   code is working but with no extra benefit. when I entered n=1855656959555656..It is taking years to execute..any further modification You can suggest.otherwise we are still stuck at same place.

Comment: can you post your code please? I see if we can speed up the performance a little bit

Comment: @Michael  How will you initialize the map.We can't initialize it with every possible count value and its respected array position during initializing.It will be more convenient if you just post your map initialization logic..

Comment: I think I have something shorter / quicker (no array access -> no bounds checks)

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. The array size can be a maximum of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (minus something usually 5 or 8, depending on the JVM capabilities). Why?. The index for an Array should be an *integer* thats a *limitation*.

Comment: yes i know that.But there must be a way to solve this recurrence relation using programming techniques. @TheLostMind

Comment: @Ashish -  Create a List and start removing objects as soon as their use is over.. You might have to call the GC explicitly in the middle. Don't keep values of *intermediate* steps.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done. So you need to solve the problem by introducing a sharding mechanism. The simplest way would be to just have arrays of arrays with a fixed length.

Comment: How array of array can solve the issue?I didn't understand?can you just elaborate.thanks

Comment: @Ashish - Array of Arrays will help you in *working around* the max size issue. Although you might get an `OutOfMemoryError`. You could escape that as well by increasing your heap space.

Comment: you need a formula for where to look up what value. for value n, you will divide n by the max array length and you know the array offset to look in, and the modulo will tell you the position

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** You really do not need this much storage for your problem at hand (as pointed out in another answer; this code fragment avoids arrays altogether to avoid bounds checks / indirection):

```
public void t(long n) {
  if (n < 5) {
    return (n == 2 || n == 3) ? 3 : 1;
  }
  long i = 5;     // Initialize variables for n == 5;
  long tn_1 = 1;  // T(n-1) = T(4) = 1;
  long tn_2 = 3;  // T(n-2) = T(3) = 3;
  long tn_3 = 1;  // T(n-3) = T(2) = 1;
  long tn_4 = 3;  // T(n-4) = T(1) = 3;
  while (true) {
    long tn = tn_1 + 3*tn_2 + 3*tn_3 + tn_4;
    if (i++ == n) {
      return tn;
    }
    tn_4 = tn_3;
    tn_3 = tn_2;
    tn_2 = tn_1;
    tn_1 = tn;
  }
}
```

To answer the **question in the title** anyway:

If your array is sparse, use a map (`TreeMap` or `HashMap`) of `Long` or `BigInteger`:

```
Map<Long,Long> t = new TreeMap<Long,Long>()
```

The memory consumption of sparse arrays depends on the number of elements actually stored, so you may want to delete values from the map that are no longer needed.

If your array is not sparse, use a 2-level array (memory consumption will depend on the pre-allocated size only):

```
public class LongArray {
  static final long BLOCK_SIZE = 0x40000000;
  long[][] storage;

  public LongArray(long size) {
    long blockCount = (size + BLOCK_SIZE - 1) / BLOCK_SIZE;
    storage = new long[][(int) blockCount];
    for (long i = 0; i < blockCount; i++) {
      if (i == blockCount - 1) {
        storage[i] = new long[(int) size - BLOCK_SIZE * (blockCount - 1)];
      } else {
        storage[i] = new long[(int) BLOCK_SIZE];
      }
    }
  }

  public long get(long index) {
    return storage[(int) (index / BLOCK_SIZE)][(int) (index % BLOCK_SIZE)];
  }

  public void put(long index, long value) {
    storage[(int) (index / BLOCK_SIZE)][(int) (index % BLOCK_SIZE)] = value;
  }
}
```

In both cases, use `t.get(index)` and `t.put(index, value)` instead of `t[index]` to access your array (if t is the name of the array).

Comment: It looks like a good option .but can you elaborate how to calculate T(i) using Map.

Comment: You use t.get(index) / t.put(index, value) instead of t[index] (if t is your array)

Comment: p.s. As pointed out elsewhere, you don't need a map or array, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive call:

```
int T(int n){
    if (n==1 || n==4){
       return 1;
    } else if (n==2 || n==3){
       return 3;
    } else {
       return T(n-1)+3*T(n-2)+3T*(n-3)+T(n-4);
    }
}
```

Edit: Time consumming. Won't work with large numbers

Comment: This is very slow code. Loop is faster. Because recursive version calculate same value multiple times.

Comment: @jhamon - each method call will be in its own stack frame.. So, *more memory* is consumed in *recursion*.

Comment: T(35) takes 8174ms, T(36) 15690ms, you never go to stack overflow with this code :)

Comment: @TheLostMind, hmm, yea you're right. I didn't think of that.

Comment: This solution is not good for very large number since it is stack based.It will throw StackOverflow error when you enter a number 1554894. @jhamon

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. Check if the value of n is equal to 1855656959555656 in the beginning or if its multiple. Suppose, the value of n is twice of 1855656959555656. Then you can create two arrays and link them together virtually. This should solve your problem but it will involve a lot of overhead.

Comment: I have tried something similar (linking two arrays virtually) but stuck at same place.I even wrote separate code for number greater than Integer.MAXValue.if(num>Integer.MAXValue){ two arrays linked solution} else {one array solution}

Comment: @Ashish Probably, you would need to refine your logic to make it work :) Also, if you are aware of ArrayList or Linked List, you can create a global Array List, and increase its size one by one whenever required. Thus, the last element of the Array List shall give you the required answer to the formula you are using. It might not even require recursion.

Comment: problem is not the size now but the performance degrades exponentially with very large number.It almost stuck for minutes.

Comment: @Ashish A recursive call for such a large number will definitely take a lot of time and memory. If you wish to execute just this program then, I would suggest hard-coding the values once and for all, at least till n=1855656959555656. Later, you can conduct an efficient search method to get the result for the required value of n.

Comment: Further,for numbers greater than 1855656959555656, you can start implementing the logic and it will take lesser time as you already have values ready up to n=1855656959555656. This will reduce the time and memory consumption for further runs of the code as values are readily available and need not be calculated.I would'nt say that this is a good programming approach, but for this program and your requirements, I think it will be a proper approach. Eventually, you will have to limit the value of n that can be taken as an input for the program.